# trying find the depth of the parenthesis but git stuck in the result

Tags: java

It always returns -1. the depth of `( ((X)) (((Y))) )` is 4 but returns always -1. where im making the wrong move?

```
public class DepthOfParenthesis {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        System.out.println(depth());
    }

    static int depth()
    {

        String S = "( ((X)) (((Y))) )";
        int current_max =0;
        int overall_max=0;
        int n =S.length();

        for(int i =0; i<n;i++)
        {
            if(S.charAt(i)=='(')
            {
                current_max++;
                if(current_max>overall_max)

                    overall_max=current_max;

            }
            else if(S.charAt(i)==')')
                {
                    if(current_max>0)
                        current_max--;
                    return -1;

                }       
        }
        if(current_max!=0)
            return -1;
        return overall_max;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got an extra return statement:

```
    else if(S.charAt(i)==')')
        {
            if(current_max>0)
                current_max--;
            return -1; //Delete this line

        }
```

Thus whenever you hit a close paren `)` it'll return -1. If you remove that it should work.

Comment: NO.. still having the same issue.

Comment: Works fine for me with that line deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
package javaquestions;

public class DepthOfParenthesis {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(depth());
    }

    static int depth() {

        String S = "( ((X)) (((Y))) )";
        int current_max = 0;
        int overall_max = 0;
        int n = S.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (S.charAt(i) == '(') {
                current_max++;
                if (current_max > overall_max)

                    overall_max = current_max;

            } else if (S.charAt(i) == ')') {
                if (current_max > 0)
                    current_max--;
                // This is were you are making mistake, when the 5 character in your array ')' is met then this else part is reached and it returns -1. Comment this line and you will get 4 as the answer.
                //return -1; 

            }
        }
        if (current_max != 0)
            return -1;
        return overall_max;
    }
}
```

More over it is not a good practice to have more than one exit points(return) for a method.

Answer (score 0):

You have a second `retrun -1` statement. 
This example shows, that even very simple things should be written with care for details to avoid simple mistakes.
Also writing well thought out code is much more fun!

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo;

import org.junit.Test;

public class DepthOfParanthesisTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        DepthOfParanthesis dop = new DepthOfParanthesis();

        int depth = dop.getDepth("( ((X)) (((Y))) )");

        assertThat(depth, equalTo(4));
    }
}

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.stream.Stream;

    public class DepthOfParanthesis {

        private static class Accumulator {

            private int max = 0;
            private int tmp = 0;

            void increment() {
                tmp++;
                if (tmp > max)
                    max = tmp;
            }

            void decrement() {
                tmp--;
            }

            public int getMax() {
                return max;
            }
        }

        public int getDepth(final String s) {

            final String OPEN = "(";
            final String CLOSE = ")";

            Accumulator acc = new Accumulator();

            streamOfTokens(s).forEach(token -> {

                if (token.equals(OPEN))
                    acc.increment();

                else if (token.equals(CLOSE))
                    acc.decrement();

            });

            return acc.getMax();
        }

        private Stream<String> streamOfTokens(final String s) {
            return Arrays.stream(s.split(""));
        }
    }
```